# Are two different hard drives the exact same size if they claim to have the same one (i.e. 1TB)?

Tags: hard-drive

**The concrete problem:**
I want to create a exact copy of a 4TB logical volume.
(By exact I mean the RAID controller will create a copy.)
Can I do this by simply using any old 4TB drive?

**The more abstract question is:**
Are two drives that claim two have the same volume (e.g. 1TB) actually of the exact same size (up to the last byte)?
So assume I would like to do a byte by byte copy including potentially corrupted ones.
Can I do this with any hard drive of the same "advertised" size?
Or do they for some reason (i.e. manufacturer calculate volume differently) differ in size slightly?

EDIT:
I assume this won't be the case as they might have (differently sized) bad segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two drives that claim two have the same volume (e.g. 1TB) should have the exact size of 1 000 000 000 000 (around 930GB) usable space. Manufacturers give a little more (a few extra sectors).

But physically, each drive has a few spare sectors that are reserved for reallocation events. So if they are not the same brand /model there may be small differences.

A 4TB logical volume may have exactly that decimal size, a little less or a little higher and may not fit into a 4TB drive.

If the volume is really 4TB (4 398 047 970 271 bytes) it will certainly not fit on a "4TB" drive which has 4 000 000 000 000 bytes.
Most of the time, exact volumes are created with true binary size (4.0 TB or TiB as named now-days to make a difference), in which case you will need a larger drive (6TB) to fit that space in (which would be 4.4 decimal "TB").

So this is what you should remember: drive sizes are din decimal TB (aka fake TB), actual data is in binary format (true TB or TiB).

So if you RAID'ed 4 x 1 TB drives into a RAID 0 and formatted that as a single volume, it should generally fit into a 4TB drive, but it may also exceed it by just a few bytes.

If a volume of 4 real TB was created out of a larger portion of an array/disk, it will definitely not fit into a 4 TB drive.

Comment: If I understand this correctly it should typically work to copy the "used" Volume of a drive byte by byte to a different one of the same size?

Comment: Yes, unless on the original drive you allocated absolutely all the space and the new one is a few bytes less spacey.